# Multiple comparisons on a mixed effects model

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, repeated-measures

I am trying to analyse some data using a mixed effect model. The data I collected represent the weight of some young animals of different genotype over time.

I am using the approach proposed here:
https://gribblelab.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/repeated-measures-anova-using-r/

In particular I'm using solution #2

So I have something like

```
require(nlme)
model <- lme(weight ~ time * Genotype, random = ~1|Animal/time, 
         data=weights)    
av <- anova(model)
```

Now, I would like to have some multiple comparisons.
Using `multcomp` I can do:

```
require(multcomp)
comp.geno <- glht(model, linfct=mcp(Genotype="Tukey"))
print(summary(comp.geno))
```

And, of course, I could do the same with time.

I have two questions:

1. How do I use `mcp` to see the interaction between Time and Genotype?
2. When I run `glht` I get this warning:

   `covariate interactions found -- default contrast might be inappropriate`

   What does it mean? Can I safely ignore it? Or what should I do to avoid it?

**EDIT:**
I found [this PDF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/vignettes/generalsiminf.pdf) that says:

> Because it is impossible to determine the parameters of interest automatically in this case, mcp() in multcomp will by default generate comparisons for the main effects only, **ignoring covariates and interactions**. Since version 1.1-2, one can specify to average over interaction terms and covariates using arguments interaction_average = TRUE and covariate_average = TRUE respectively, whereas versions older than 1.0-0 automatically averaged over interaction terms. **We suggest to the users, however, that they write out, manually, the set of contrasts they want.** One should do this whenever there is doubt about what the default contrasts measure, which typically happens in models with higher order interaction terms. We refer to Hsu (1996), Chapter~7, and Searle (1971), Chapter~7.3, for further discussions and examples on this issue.

I do not have access to those books, but maybe someone here has?

Comment: Have a look at InvivoStat ([invivostat.co.uk](http://invivostat.co.uk)), it should do the type of analysis that you are looking for

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If `time` and `Genotype` are both categorical predictors as they appear to be, and you are interested in comparing all time/Genotype pairs to each other, then you can just create one interaction variable, and use Tukey contrasts on it:

```
weights$TimeGeno <- interaction(weigths$Time, weights$Geno)
model <- lme(weight ~ TimeGeno, random = ~1|Animal/time, data=weights) 
comp.timegeno <- glht(model, linfct=mcp(TimeGeno="Tukey"))
```

If you are interested in other contrasts, then you can use the fact that the `linfct` argument can take a matrix of coefficients for the contrasts - this way you can set up exactly the comparisons you want.

**EDIT**

There appears some concern in the comments that the model fitted with the `TimeGeno` predictor is different from the original model fitted with the `Time * Genotype` predictor. *This is not the case*, the models are equivalent. The only difference is in the parametrization of the fixed effects, which is set up to make it easier to use the `glht` function.

I have used one of the built-in datasets (it has Diet instead of Genotype) to demonstrate that the two approaches have the same likelihood, predicted values, etc:

```
> # extract a subset of a built-in dataset for the example
> data(BodyWeight)
> ex <- as.data.frame(subset(BodyWeight, Time %in% c(1, 22, 44)))
> ex$Time <- factor(ex$Time)
> 
> #create interaction variable
> ex$TimeDiet <- interaction(ex$Time, ex$Diet)
    > 
    > model1 <- lme(weight ~ Time * Diet, random = ~1|Rat/Time,  data=ex)    
    > model2 <- lme(weight ~ TimeDiet, random = ~1|Rat/Time, data=ex)    
    > 
    > # the degrees of freedom, AIC, BIC, log-likelihood are all the same 
    > anova(model1, model2)
           Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik
    model1     1 12 367.4266 387.3893 -171.7133
    model2     2 12 367.4266 387.3893 -171.7133
    Warning message:
    In anova.lme(model1, model2) :
      fitted objects with different fixed effects. REML comparisons are not meaningful.
    > 
    > # the second model collapses the main and interaction effects of the first model
    > anova(model1)
                numDF denDF   F-value p-value
    (Intercept)     1    26 1719.5059  <.0001
    Time            2    26   28.9986  <.0001
    Diet            2    13   85.3659  <.0001
    Time:Diet       4    26    1.7610  0.1671
    > anova(model2)
                numDF denDF   F-value p-value
    (Intercept)     1    24 1719.5059  <.0001
    TimeDiet        8    24   29.4716  <.0001
    > 
    > # they give the same predicted values
    > newdata <- expand.grid(Time=levels(ex$Time), Diet=levels(ex$Diet))
    > newdata$TimeDiet <- interaction(newdata$Time, newdata$Diet)
> newdata$pred1 <- predict(model1, newdata=newdata, level=0)
    > newdata$pred2 <- predict(model2, newdata=newdata, level=0)
> newdata
  Time Diet TimeDiet   pred1   pred2
1    1    1      1.1 250.625 250.625
2   22    1     22.1 261.875 261.875
3   44    1     44.1 267.250 267.250
4    1    2      1.2 453.750 453.750
5   22    2     22.2 475.000 475.000
6   44    2     44.2 488.750 488.750
7    1    3      1.3 508.750 508.750
8   22    3     22.3 518.250 518.250
9   44    3     44.3 530.000 530.000
```

The only difference is that what hypotheses are easy to test. For example, in the first model it is easy to test whether the two predictors interact, in the second model there is no explicit test for this. On the other hand, the joint effect of the two predictors is easy to test in the second model, but not the first one. The other hypotheses are testable, it is just more work to set those up.

Comment: `glht` uses the degrees of freedom given in the lme model. I'm not sure these degrees of freedom are appropriate... ?

Comment: I am also curious how this is best done. This approach, however, is giving effects from a different model - one that essentially only tests for an interaction. The second model does not include the two potential main effects at all. This does not seem to be an appropriate method for checking the effects in the first model.

Comment: @Aniko, I was thinking of combining 2 categorical variable into one as you just did, but I hesited because just one of the variables is within subject, the other is between. Can you confirm that this doesn't mather? I noticed that in the example you keep `Animal/time` which now is not one of the factors. Does lme really `understand` this?

Comment: @toto_tico, I have edited the response to show that the second model is equivalent to the first one.

Comment: @Aniko, I am sure that models are not equivalent. Both throws significant results for the interaction, but the results are different. Just take a look to the F values (that indirectly relates to the effect size). You would also have to check for the assumptions of anova (normality and homogeneity of variances) for both models. I am completely sure that the residuals will change. My question is related to how the model would interpret the a factor that is not part of the formula.

Comment: @Aniko, I am blind, the interaction is not significant in the first model. What do you mean by the models are equivalent then?

Comment: @Aniko, Basically `lme(weight ~ TimeDiet, random = ~1|Rat/Time, data=ex)` vs `lme(weight ~ TimeDiet,  data=ex) `?

Comment: @toto_tico, I gave you a reproducible example. Why don't you try `all.equal(resid(model1), resid(model2))` and see that they are the same before guessing otherwise? Only the fixed effects parametrization is different. `TimeDiet` is not a pure interaction term, and it is not equivalent to `Time:Diet`, but rather to `Time + Diet + Time:Diet`.

Comment: @toto_tico, There is no requirement for the random effects terms appear in the fixed effects part, in fact typically they don't.

Comment: @Aniko, I tried and effectively the residuals are the same. I am puzzled. Unfortunately I couldn't try the formula without the random effect because the lme doesn't allow it. I am guessing the lme is smart enough to interpret the data. Thanks